# How to use NodeJS package in Flutter web app

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, flutter-web, web-midi

I have a Flutter web app that needs to be able to create a virtual midi device. For this, the only option seems to be to use the [easymidi NodeJS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easymidi). What is the best way of connecting a NodeJS script to a flutter app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to javascript from flutter web. Best way is to use `dart:js` library.

Add your custom js file to web directory a make sure that it's loaded

```
<head>
    <script src="your.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

For example

```js
function info(text) {
    alert(text)
}
```

Calling from dart:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

js.context.callMethod('info', ['Hello!']);
```